# How to remove namespace from soap msg

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I need transform Soap Message to XML message.
I have a problem with get correct xml message.

Input message is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <a1:mojkomunikat xmlns:a1="http://costam">
            <a1:message>
                <a1:msgHeader>
                </a1:msgHeader>
                <a1:msgData>
                    <a1:some>duzo danych</a1:some>
                </a1:msgData>
            </a1:message>
        </a1:mojkomunikat>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

the output message is to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msg>
    <parameters>
        <parameter>
            <key>content</key>
            <value><![CDATA[<some>duzo danych</some>]]></value>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</msg>
```

I try use this transformer but not works.
I the root element is still namespace unfortunately :(

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:a1="http://costam" 
        version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <msg>
            <parameters>
                <parameter>
                    <key>content</key>
                    <value><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//a1:msgData/*"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text></value>
                </parameter>
            </parameters>
        </msg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but not works

What am i doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the output you are actually getting, as when I try your XSLT the `msg` is in no namespace. You may be getting some unused namespace declarations on it, but these can be removed by `exclude-result-prefixes`. `msg` itself is not in a namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `exclude-result-prefixes` in `<xsl:stylesheet>`. This ensures the namespaces are not added in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:a1="http://costam" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="S a1">
```